# WP activate hook and adding rows to database table

Tags: php, wordpress

in my function activate plugin i adding to plugin table default rows:

```
$args = array(
                    "setting_name" => 'first',
                    "setting_value" => 'value'
                );
                $args2 = array(
                    "setting_name" => 'second',
                    "setting_value" => 'value'
                );
                $args3 = array(
                    "setting_name" => 'third',
                    "setting_value" => 'value'
                );
                $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."x", $args);
                $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."y", $args2);
                $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."z", $args2);
```

how to shorten this code?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$settings = array('x' => array(
                    "setting_name" => 'first',
                    "setting_value" => 'value'
                ),
                'y' => array(
                    "setting_name" => 'second',
                    "setting_value" => 'value'
                ),
                'z' => array(
                    "setting_name" => 'third',
                    "setting_value" => 'value'
                )
    );

foreach($settings as $table => $args){ 
  $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.$table, $args);
}
```